# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have Windows service based in C# which connects to multiple clients over web using TCP Port. Server has static IP, which helps clients to locate the server. I have posted the code here.

```
TcpListener tcp = new TcpListener(ipAddr, portNo);

tcp.Start();

listening = true;

while (listening)
{
    Socket mySocket = null;

    // Blocks until a client has connected to the server 
    try
    {
        mySocket = tcp.AcceptSocket();
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        byte[] bReceive = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2];
        int i = mySocket.Receive(bReceive);
        byte[] databyte = new byte[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            databyte[j] = bReceive[j];
        }

        Analysis(databyte, mySocket);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        logger.Error(exc);
    }
}

listening = false;
tcp.Stop();
```

At times I get one of these two errors which is closing the connection and all the clients get disconnected:

1. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at
   `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags).`
2. An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine at

   `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)`

These errors are not periodic, but are causing all the clients to disconnect whenever they appear. The service connects to approximately 300 clients.

**Edit 1:**
As per suggestion of @Sean H, I have modified the code  to read data asynchronously. Following is the code:

```
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

//constructor 
public Server()
{
    listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.5"), 9000));
    listener.Listen(300);
    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnConnectRequest), listener);
    //Console.Write("Server Running...\r\n");
}

public void OnConnectRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket accepted = listener.EndAccept(ar);
    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnConnectRequest), listener);
    NewConnection(accepted);
}

//send a string message over a TCP socket 
public void sendMSG(Byte[] bSendData, ref Socket mySocket)
{
    //some code which sends data according to my protocol
    int numBytes = 0;

    try
    {
        if (mySocket.Connected)
        {
            if ((numBytes = mySocket.Send(bSendData, bSendData.Length, 0)) == -1)
            {
                logger.Error("Socket Error: Cannot Send Packet (Custom Error by me)");
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Error("Link Failed - Socket closed (Custom Error by me)");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        logger.Error(exc);
    }
}

public void receiveMSG(ref Socket mySocket)
{
    byte[] bReceive = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2];
    int i = mySocket.Receive(bReceive);
    byte[] databyte = new byte[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        databyte[j] = bReceive[j];
    }

    Analysis(databyte, mySocket);
}


//function called whenever a NEW CLIENT is connected
public void NewConnection(Socket sockClient)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("user {0} has joined", sockClient.RemoteEndPoint);
    //byte[] msg = new byte[20];
    receiveMSG(ref sockClient);
    //sockClient.Receive(msg);
}
```

This works great in test environment.

I have not deployed it on production, reason being that, how would server know if the data what it has received is completed or there is a part of string that is still to be transmitted from client to server. I cannot know the actual behavior of Windows service until I deploy it on production, since I have 4 clients in test environment as compared to 300 in the production.

However @Sean H's advice turned great because, now the server is not blocked until a request from client is processed. It is listening to multiple clients at same moment.

I'm relatively new to this sort of TCP/IP programming, my question may seem foolish...

Comment: It is an entirely normal mishap, networks are not 100.000% reliable.  The error message is boilerplate from the OS, "remote host" and "host machine" are not accurate when you are the host.  It means the client.  If all of them die at the same time then maybe somebody rebooted a router or ran his car into a utility pole.  Things you cannot find out with software.  Just ensure that clients can reconnect again.

Comment: This was running fine when we had 5-6 clients, as the number of clients grew, the service started crashing. However after 25-30 mins, clients get reconnected. But we cannot afford such long time. Can you suggest some reconnection code so that we reconnect to the client immediately.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem. While your Analysis(byte, Socket) method is running, your server is unable to accept more connections. Once you accept a socket from a client, you are no longer listening on that port until you finish your work and call the .AcceptSocket() method again.

Instead, you should fire off the work to an asynchronous method, and begin listening once again after the current client connection is bound. This is a great example of what you want to do.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: For all we know, `Analysis` is a short method that does arrange for the remainder of the work to be dealt with off-thread. Certainly the current problem description describes *multiple* clients which isn't possible given the shown code and assuming an entirely synchronous `Analysis` - that would be the typical "why can I not connect more than one client?" question.

Comment: Regardless of how quickly the Analysis method runs, it is clear that the server is not listening on a port in the remainder of the loop after AcceptSocket(). The thread is put to sleep for a half-second for some reason as well, so that's a substantial time in the dark. The issue may not manifest if a few clients are connecting infrequently, but will appear with greater frequency once more clients are connected. This is the behavior described in the question.

Comment: Thanks @SeanH for the advice, I will change the code and figure it out if this works.

Comment: The client wont send `<EOF>` as required by asynchronous listening of server port. @SeanH please advice. I cannot modify the client's logic. It's a device with built in functionality. Moreover the error says `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` at the line where code to receive data from client is written. Is it because the thread is paused with other client or any other reason?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your updated code? Also, is the payload sent by the client well-known, to the point where you can know when you have received the full set of data you are expecting?

Comment: I think with your edit you may be creating a race condition in your code. I will dig into it and edit my answer shortly.

Comment: This code has created lot more troubles, I've restored the previous code now. For me the problem with new code seemed that socket was not waiting until it received complete data, instead it was getting partial strings, which made the application unstable

Comment: Yeah, that's where I think something in your code was mixing up the binding of new sockets and not fully reading data from the existing ones. Something seems off about it, but I haven't quite found it.

Comment: I think I see your issue. You cannot necessarily guarantee that one read will receive all of the bytes that the client has sent. You should be reading into a buffer, and copying the bytes from that buffer out to a stream, that contains all of your data. I will see if I can put together an example in my answer.

Comment: I guess there socket read gets timed out before reading is completed. Hence the error. I'm not sure if i'm right. What do you suggest i should do next?